# Move unique files from a folder with duplicates files

Tags: bash, files, wildcards, mv, file-management

Well to put it simply, I have duplicate files in a folder, with this form:

```
file.ext
file(1).ext
file(2).ext
file(3).ext
otherfile.ext
otherfile(1).ext
otherfile(2).ext
...
```

I want to move only `file.ext` and `otherfile.ext` to another folder. Is it possible to do it in `bash`?

I thought that maybe `awk` would be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash:`

```
shopt -s extglob # activates extended pattern matching features
mv !(*\(+([0-9])\)).ext /path/to/target/
```

The regular expression matches all files, that don't end with `(n).ext`, where `n` is one or more numbers: `+([0-9])`.

You can check it with `echo`:

```
echo !(*\(+([0-9])\)).ext
```

Prints:

```
file.ext otherfile.ext
```

Comment: `extglob` is not regex.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 It isn't what's usually called “regex”, but it *is* a regular expression, with a different syntax from the usual regex syntax. Well, except that the `!` operator isn't a regular expression feature.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If we can assume that any file whose name contains `(` should be ignored, you could just do:

```
shopt -s extglob ## turns on fancy glob patterns
mv !(*\(*) /path/to/target
```

If you can have other names that contain `(` or if you need to only move those files which are duplicated, you can do:

```
for f in *\(*; do 
    ## Does this file have an original?
    [[ -e "${f%%(*}.${f##*.}" ]] && 
        ## Move the original
        mv "${f%%(*}.${f##*.}" /path/to/target; 
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```
$ ls  *ext | grep -P '[^)]\.ext' | xargs -iXXxxFILEXXxx mv XXxxFILEXXxx target/
```

`grep` will filter out files with brackets in names and `xargs` will run command `mv` on results. The ugly `XXxxFILEXXxx` label is for placing file names as `mv` argument.

Comment: [Parsing `ls` is usually best avoided.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).